# How acccess mutation from one store file for another store file?

Tags: vuex, vuex-modules

How can I access a mutation from one file in my `store` folder  that exists in another file in my `store` folder?

Here's my directory:

```
store/
     user.js
     loading.js
```

In `user.js` I have:

```
  async googleSignInRedirect({ commit }) {
    try {
      const result = await this.$fire.auth.getRedirectResult()
      if (result.credential) {
        // const credential = result.credential
        // console.log('got a credential? ', credential)
        this.$router.replace('/')
        commit('loading/SET_LOADING', false) //< -- what is correct way to write this ?
      }
      return null
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  },
```

Here is the `loading.js` code:

```
export const state = () => ({
  loading: false
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_LOADING(state, payload) {
    state.loading = payload
  }
}
```

How can I access `loading.js` from `user.js` ? If I do the above style, I get the following error in console:

```
vuex.esm.js?2f62:791 [vuex] unknown local mutation type: loading/SET_LOADING, global type: user/loading/SET_LOADING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `{ root: true }` as the final argument to `commit`, so:

```js
  async googleSignInRedirect({ commit }) {
    try {
      const result = await this.$fire.auth.getRedirectResult()
      if (result.credential) {
        this.$router.replace('/')
        commit('loading/SET_LOADING', false, { root: true })
      }
      return null
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

You can find more details in the [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit).

Comment: thx! Now I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerModule' of undefined` . Is that because I am being redirected to Google sign in page (outside of my app) and then back to my app?

Comment: @redshift That's an error unrelated to your question above. Note that with Nuxt, you will need to have an `index.js` file in your `~/store` directory.

Comment: Thanks. What do i put in the `index.js` file? The nuxt docs use a `counter` example but i don't have a counter...

Comment: @redshift You can just create an empty file, or at most: `export const state = () => ({})`